# JUnit Parallel Testing

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm trying to run a piece of code that I found online to run JUnit test in parallel but the only thing I've modified is the URL to hit my local host.  Problem is I'm constantly getting the following error and even though I've setup selenium grid many times and know how to set paths etc. I don't know how to fix this one.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.
```

here's the code

```
package AutomationFrameWork;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.model.RunnerScheduler;

public class Parallelized extends Parameterized {

  private static class ThreadPoolScheduler implements RunnerScheduler {
    private ExecutorService executor; 

    public ThreadPoolScheduler() {
      String threads = System.getProperty("junit.parallel.threads", "16");
      int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(threads);
      executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    }

    @Override
    public void finished() {
      executor.shutdown();
      try {
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
      executor.submit(childStatement);
    }
  }

  public Parallelized(Class<?> klass) throws Throwable {
    super(klass);
    setScheduler(new ThreadPoolScheduler());
  }
}

package AutomationFrameWork;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

@RunWith(Parallelized.class)
public class JUnitParallel {
  private String platform;
  private String browserName;
  private String browserVersion;
  private WebDriver driver;

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static LinkedList<String[]> getEnvironments() throws Exception {
    LinkedList<String[]> env = new LinkedList<String[]>();
    env.add(new String[]{Platform.WINDOWS.toString(), "chrome", "27"});
    env.add(new String[]{Platform.WINDOWS.toString(),"firefox","20"});
    env.add(new String[]{Platform.WINDOWS.toString(),"ie","11"});
    env.add(new String[]{Platform.WINDOWS.toString(),"safari","5.1.7"});

    //add more browsers here

    return env;
  }


  public JUnitParallel(String platform, String browserName, String browserVersion) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.browserName = browserName;
    this.browserVersion = browserVersion;
  }



  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {  
    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capability.setCapability("platform", platform);
    capability.setCapability("browser", browserName);
    capability.setCapability("browserVersion", browserVersion);
    capability.setCapability("build", "JUnit-Parallel");
    capability.setCapability("InternetExplorerDriverServer.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION",true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\path to driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
      new URL("http://localhost:7777".concat("/wd/hub")),
      capability
    );  
  }  

  @Test  
  public void testSimple() throws Exception {  
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + title);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.sendKeys("BrowserStack");
    element.submit();
    driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
    File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
      FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("Screenshot.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {  
    driver.quit();  
  }
}
```

Comment: "C:\\Users\\path to driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");" is that the correct path to your driver?

Comment: I've replaced the correct path with 'path to driver' but on my machine its correct

Comment: Try one / slash instead